# PHP to SMS - Change the "From Name"

Tags: php, sms

I am writing a small web app that uses PHP code to email a phone number (the person with the phone number sees it as a text message, and not as an email of course).  Every phone service has email to text.  For example, Verizon in the US uses @vtext.com.

My problem is this, the FROM on the SMS always says "6245" which is apparently standard for SMS's from the Verizon email domain (vtext.com).  Can I change this in code with a more human readable From rather than this seemingly random number?

Here is my code using PHP mailer:

```
            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $from = filter_var($from, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $message .= $guest . ' waiting at Office. Checked in at ';
            $message .= strftime("%l:%M %p (%A %b %e, %Y)", time());

            // PHP SMTP mail version

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE onduty = 1");

            $recipients = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $recipients[] = $row['phone'] . $row['carrier'];

            }

            foreach ($recipients as $email) {
                $mail -> AddAddress($email);

            }

            $from_name = "Riverstone Notification";
            $subject = "Person in Office";

            $mail -> IsSMTP();
            $mail -> Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            $mail -> Port = 25;
            $mail -> SMTPAuth = false;
            $mail -> Username = "EMAIL_USER";
            $mail -> Password = "EMAIL_PASS";
            $mail -> FromName = $from_name;
            $mail -> From = $from;
            $mail -> Subject = $subject;
            $mail -> Body = $message;

            $result = $mail -> Send();
```

Comment: You could always use a service that does what you want. I've looked into Tropo(https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp) before, and they seem to have an interesting service.

Comment: That looks good, though it seems to be a paid service which is not what I am looking for, but +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: Check with Verizon / vtext.com how to set the from number. They might be able to tell you.

Comment: If you want to send texts without going through the carrier's email services, you'll have to pay for it. Sending it through the carriers is nice for users though, since they shouldn't get charged for those texts, assuming they don't have an unlimited plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, when you're using the Verizon's service, that no. is going to be standard, because it comes from Verizon's SMS gateway.
You would have to get a paid service, if you need flexibility on that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the same thing your dealing with, 
When I use to send sms (Tmobile = tmomail.net) If I don't put an email with the same ending as my website in the $headers, it adds My hosting user id at secureserver.net... Bunch of noise.... When I add From:3333@abc.com and say my website is abc.com it keeps it clean. From the research I've gotten, its does that to try and stop spam, so it looks for something to say this email is coming from this site type of thing...